# Socket io and Safari Error -9807

Tags: safari, socket.io

I got an error with Safari that I don't have with other Browsers, with the use of socketIo. 
Error is:"WebSocket network error: OSStatus Error -9807: Invalid certificate chain"
It does not happen on Chrome and Opera.
I tried some research without success. 
Any clue is more than welcome. 
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution which was quite obvious. Renew the SSL certificate, trust it when browse to the app and everything was all good.